# ssh host key verification failed if run with subprocess

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, real-time

I've got two computers running Linux a@A and b@B, a microphone being connected to B.
Using A, I log in into b@B to launch a python script which has the possibility to listen to the microphone in real time.

Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*-coding:Latin-1 -*

import threading
import time
import pygame
import sys
import subprocess
import os
import signal

global listenProcess
global listenProcess2

listenProcess = subprocess.Popen('arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f dat'.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
listenProcess2 = subprocess.Popen('ssh -C a@A aplay -f dat'.split(), stdin=listenProcess.stdout, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

If I launch the command:

```
arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f dat | ssh -C a@A aplay -f dat
```

it works perfectly fine and I can listen to what is recorded by the microphone. But if it is from my python script, it raises the following error:

> Host key verification failed

I've tried to "clean" the known_hosts file as suggested when the error is raised.
I've also tried paramiko but does not seem to be my solution.

I've ran out of ideas.

Thanks

EDIT:
Running `arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f dat | ssh -v -C bertrand@192.168.1.33 aplay -f dat`
displays :

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Documents $ arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f dat | ssh -v -C bertrand@192.168.1.33 aplay -f dat
Recording WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Stereo
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.33 [192.168.1.33] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com zlib@openssh.com
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA e1:fc:46:c9:5f:66:f8:d5:8f:13:27:cb:2d:a5:7b:17
debug1: Host '192.168.1.33' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.1.33 ([192.168.1.33]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = fr_FR.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: aplay -f dat
Playing WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Stereo
```

As it is launched in command line, it is working.

EDIT:
Ok, I think I might have found the reason: As my whole python script launches a fullscreen display with pygame on my remote pc, I need to launch the script with sudo. Thus I think when it launches ssh with subprocess, it is also trying to connect as sudo on computer A. The reason I think that is that the simple version of my code is working, but if I launch it as sudo, it asks for my password. Problem is, I still need to launch the script as sudo.

Comment: `split` introduces the risk of splitting incorrectly - maybe this is the cause. Either construct the sequence yourself or use `shell=True` (with due considerations).

Comment: yes, listenProcess2 = subprocess.Popen('ssh -C a@A aplay -f dat', shell='True', stdin=listenProcess.stdout, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) raises the same error

Comment: You quoted True there. I think it needs to be boolean, not a string

Comment: Same for listenProcess2 = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '-C', 'a@A', 'aplay', '-f', 'dat'], stdin=listenProcess.stdout, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: Essential checks - if the script runs as the same user, checking `ssh -v(vv)` output - done?

Comment: And if you SSH to your machines individually, outside of python, there is no issue? You're sure of that?

Comment: @cricket_007 I've just tried with shell=True, not working :-(

Comment: @cricket_007 and yes I confirm it is working if I launch the command in a shell scrypt

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I've added -v and it writes "'OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015\r\n'"

Comment: you must've added `-V` instead of `-v`. If not, check your ssh docs for the switch for verbose output.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I've edit my question to show the verbose output

Comment: It's all good, no errors. Now, what is the diagnostic output in the case where the problem occurs?

Comment: The only output is the first line. The one in my comment above. The rest is not displayed

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Important thing, the python script is launched with sudo. That's what may cause the error.

Comment: Diagnostic output is typically sent to stderr. Do you even read it in your script?

Comment: Sure, `sudo` runs the command as root. You need to set up `ssh` for root to authenticate to your server with public key, too, if you wish it to be that way.

Comment: The error displayed by stderr was "Host key verification failed". Regarding the ssh connection, I added a key so that password is not required. But this does not apply to root. I'm trying to connect as root without asking for a password... to see if it will make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Warning:**
The solution might not be for everyone as it is not totally safe but for my particular problem where my 2 computers are directly connected without internet connection, the risk is not high.

**Solution:**
On the server, I did this:

```
sudo su - root # log in as root
ssh-keygen -t rsa # generate a rsa key
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh b@B 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys' # add the key to the other computer
service ssh restart # restart ssh just in case
```

This way it's working. Thanks for your help.